# \includepdf position

Tags: boxes, minipage, pdfpages, includegraphics

I'm writing a report including some pdf cropped cause the rest of the page is blank, but neither with a minipage I can put it between the sentences.

Here is the code:

```
    \section{prova}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includepdf[clip, trim=10mm 5mm 5mm 10mm]{analisipreli/tabellasex.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[2]
```

[image]

Comment: `\includepdf` is for whole pages, use `\includegraphics` to include a pdf as part of a page

Comment: also if you do not want it to float do not put it in a figure, just use it directly between the paragraphs.

Comment: with \includegraphics[trim= 10mm 5mm 5mm 10mm, clip]{analisipreli/tabellasex.pdf} goes in the next page..

Comment: I think that I'm not cropping the pdf correctly; someone can tell me how does it work? because I'd like just the upper part of my pdf file except for the margins.

Comment: To only trim from above, use something like `trim=0mm 0mm 0mm 10mm`. The order is left, lower, right, upper.